# I need a line dividing 2 nested constraint layouts exactly in the center

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to learn Android and as part of it building a Basketball score calc app for two teams.

As part of this, I used 2 constraint layouts nested inside a constraint layout. One for each team.

1. I want a line between those nested constraint layouts so as to divide bot the teams and I am trying to use the guideline but it won't work !!
2. After the above I want to try making a box around that constraint views, is there a way to achieve that?
3. I am pretty sure the attached code is not even close to perfect. Can you all please point out the mistakes I have done in the attached code so that I can learn from them?

Can someone please help me explain how we achieve these?

Thanks in advance. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgyZv.jpg)

Comment: it's kinda hard to tell what you want, can you add your XML code? and at least edit the picture to show where the line should be?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want a line in the middle you can place simple view like this :
   `

   ```
   <View
       android:layout_width="20dp"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>
   ```
2. If you want a box around your score you can add background to your 'TextView/ImageView' that represent score, look in the internet how to create `ShapeDrawable` and apply it
3. Do it with one ConstraintLayout